# Map: check wether a point is on polyline or not

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Problem : We have multiple polylines on map and when a user taps on a polyline need to check wether that point is on poly line or not and also the latlong of the clicked point is need to be extracted.

Known :

LatLong can be extracted by setting click listener on map and to detect polyline click we can have polyline click listener, but need a solution which combines both. That is whenever a user taps on polyline we can extract the reasonably correct latlong for that point.( not for tap/click on map which are not on the polyline)

Comment: Seems like a reasonable request - ideally it would be a parameter to the callback - since that doesn't seem available (do you get both callbacks (map/polyline) i wonder?) then I'd say implement the polyline listener in your mapclick listener by using the android map utility PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath providing it the union of your multiple polylines (or keep them unique if you need to know which polyline).  One benefit of this is you can customize the tolerance of the polyline touch as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create a structure to store the created polylines:

```
List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
```

And add every polyline that you create to the `List`:

```
polylines.add(mMap.addPolyline(yourPolylineOptions));
```

Then you can use the `PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath` method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) to know whether a polyline has been clicked (using a 100 meter tolerance in this example. This means that a polyline is considered clicked if the user click 100 meters away from the polyline or less):

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng click) {
            boolean isPolylineClicked = false;
            for (Polyline polyline : polylines) {
                if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(click, polyline.getPoints(), false, 100)) {
                    isPolylineClicked = true;
                    // Polyline clicked!
                }
            }

            if (!isPolylineClicked) {
                // Other OnMapClickListener behavior
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, it works , but problem is click on polyline hinders the map click event any solution for that

Comment: You can add your custom `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener` if no polyline has been clicked. Take a look at my updated answer